# Generate SessionID based on given rules using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to solve SQL question for interview preparation. Please can someone help me understand on approach to solve it.

```
Question: 
Generate sessionID based on userid and logintime values.
Input: (userid integer,logintime datetime)
Output: userid, logintime, sessionID

Rules:
1. New user will get next sessionID
2. When a user logins after 30 mins of its previous login time, you should 
   give next sessionID.

Input:
1 9:00 AM
2 9:10 AM
1 9:25 AM
3 12:34 PM
1 3:10 PM

Output:
1 9:00 AM 1
2 9:10 AM 2
1 9:25 AM 1 -- Since User 1 logged in within 30 mins we assigned same sessionID
3 12:34 PM 3
1 3:10 PM 4 -- Again, now user logged in after 30 mins we assigned next sessionid after 3, which is 4
```

Comment: If you have an interview question, it should be you trying to answer it, not us; we're not the ones doing the interview. If you want to show your attempts, and explain why they aren't working, we can point you in the right direction, but Stack Overflow isn't the place for asking us to do the work for you; that's up to you and no one else.

Comment: @Larnu: This is not an interview question which I received. Nor, I am trying to cheat. I am preparing for interview and I stumbled across this question and trying to solve it  but unable to solve it.

Comment: So show us what you *have* tried. What research have you performed and what didn't you understand about it?

Comment: Not sure where you found this practice question but it is tragically flawed. There isn't enough information to answer this. And frankly the design of this is really bad. The result of this question in your interview and mine sound as though they would be very different. I would point out the fallacy of a design pattern like this and suggest a better option instead of providing an "answer". Such is the case with nearly all technical type questions at interviews. They are too shallow to be useful.

Comment: I actually like to start a technical discussion in sql interviews with "tell me at least one way I can get the current system time using t-sql". I am not kidding that more than 50% of the interviews have ended with that question. The amount of people who claim 5+ years of t-sql experience that can't answer a question that is paramount to queries in every industry is truly shocking.

Answer (score 0):

I'll not write down an answer, that can be cheating.

If possible always try to clear up things with your interviewers, they are the ultimate authority here.

To me, this looks like a classical insert or update question, query the actual user session to see if it was idle for more than 30 minutes and proceed as asked.

How you will achieve it, getting next id, depends on you. You can use sequence or auto identity and must know the difference and disadvantages and advantages of both solutions.

**UPDATE**

Since OP clarified it's not an actual interview question, just a preparation for one I can go further.

I can create a `SP_SaveSession` stored procedure and inside it put a merge or an old 'IF'. A query can search for any session for the userId in the last 30 minutes if find one update it (timestamp), if not insert a new session.

In the end, the stored procedure can repeat the first query, fetching any session for that userId in the last 30 minutes. By the logic this query can return only one row.

Comment: This question is not taken from interviews. I came across this question while "practicing" questions and was trying to solve it but am unable to solve.

Comment: @user2961127, where did you find question while practicing, can you send me link for that?